# Why the "There were no net reputation changes on this day" despite no question/answer deleted and no votes received

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I ran across on [one of my SE profile pages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210924042440/https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation)):

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

No question/answer were deleted (including by roomba), I received no votes this day, I didn't downvote anyone and I didn't retract an accept choice.

What could explain the appearance of this message?